# The definition of a homogeneous vector bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, vector-bundles

For a homogeneous space $G/H$ a **homogeneous vector bundle** has a total space of the form $G \times_{\rho} V$, where $(V,\rho)$ is a representation of $H$ and $G \times_{\rho} V$ is the set of equivalence classes of elements of $G \times V$ where $(gh,v) ~ (g,hv)$. The projection map is then defined by $\pi([g,v]) = g H$. I guess that there is an equivalent version of the definition of a homogeneous vector bundle that does not explicitly mention any $H$-module. Something as a vector bundle $F$ together with a left $G$-action $G \times F \to F$ . . .  but this looks too weak . . . what is the definition (assuming it exists) and how is the equivalence established?

Comment: See eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivariant_bundle where the base space has a transitive action. It's a theorem that every such equivariant vector bundle looks like the associated bundle using a representation as in the definition you give.

Comment: From this how can one see that the fiber gives a representation of H?

Comment: Pick a point x in the base X, let H be the stabilizer of x. Then X is isomorphic to G/H as a G-space, and the G-action on the total space restricts to an H action that maps the fibre over X to itself.